# Beginner in AJAX can't load script in called page

Tags: ajax, tags, append

I am trying to call page to show on my "index" page using AJAX, but the loaded page does not recognize the head tags i put in the "head" on the "index" page... I've tried to "append" the needed three scripts this way, but it did not work... I would appreciate some help by any of you. Thank's so much :).

```
$( "#div" ).click(function(){   

  $('#div2').delay(3400).fadeIn(1000, 'jswing', {queue:false}); 

  $.ajax({ 
         url: 'pages/dizain.php',   
         success: function(response) {
        $("#div2").html(response);
            }
        });

var script1 = document.createElement( 'script1' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '../scripts/yoxview/yox.js';

    var script2 = document.createElement( 'script2' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '../scripts/yoxview/yoxview-init.js';

    var script3 = document.createElement( 'script3' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/yoxview/jquery.yoxview-2.2.min.js';



 $("#durjachut").append( script1);
 $("#durjachut").append( script2);
 $("#durjachut").append( script3); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.createElement( 'script1' );` creates: `<script1>`, which is not a valid tag. You just need "script".

Comment: But if i want to append them into the head of he "#durjachut" HTML, should i have $("#durjachut").append( script1); $("#durjachut").append( script2); etc or $("#durjachut").append( script);. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

it should be document.createElement("script"); for all three calls rather than script1 script2 etc because those arent valid tags

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement

Comment: But if i want to append them into the head of he "#durjachut" HTML, should i have $("#durjachut").append( script1); $("#durjachut").append( script2); etc or $("#durjachut").append( script);. Thanks ;)

Comment: ' $("#durjachut").append( script1);
 $("#durjachut").append( script2);
 $("#durjachut").append( script3);' because those are variable names